# MongoDB $and query only works on Strings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter out data based on search criteria in mongoDb.

Here is the query:

```
exports.getParkingListByCriteria = async (req, res) => {
  const cityQuery = req.body.city;
  const stateQuery = req.body.state;
  const countryQuery = req.body.country;
  const zipQuery = req.body.zipCode;
  try {
    const filter = await Parking.find({
      $and: [
        {
          "location.city": { $regex: new RegExp(cityQuery, ($options = "i")) },
          "location.state": { $regex: new RegExp(stateQuery, ($options = "i"))},
          "location.country": { $regex: new RegExp(countryQuery, ($options = "i"))},
          "location.zipCode": zipQuery,
        },
      ],
    });
    res.status(200).send(filter);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

City, state and country are stored as a `String` and zipCode is stored as a `Number` in mongoose model.

city, state and country filter was just working fine. It was giving me an intended results but then I added a zipCode query and now city, state and countries filter is also giving an empty array.

request I am sending from postman:

```
{
    "city": "edmund",
    "state": "lousinia",
    "country":"australia",
    "zipCode": 49755
}
```

All are stored in a one collection like shown below:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "62cc46e920782c4be0673d50"},
"merchantId": {"$oid": 62c950ebc96c2b690028be8b"},
"contactInfo": {"name": "Ronda Green", "phoneNumber": 9104933588},
"about": "Laborum non minim ad",
"location":
    {"address": "349 scott avenue",
     "city": "edmund",
     "state": "louisiana",
     "zipCode": 49755,
     "country": "australia"},
"price": 18,
"parkingType": "parkingLot",
"parkingInfo": [{"parkingName": "College Place","_id":"$oid":"62cc46e920782c4be0673d51"},"default": []}],
"totalSpots": [168],
"parkingSpotType": ["Motorbike","Large"],
"coordinates": 
    {"lng": 1.522645,
     "lat": 125.939061},
"status": "active",
"isFeePaid": false,
"availability": [],
"specialEvents": [],
"__v": 0}
```

Before the introduction of zipQuery to the code every individual request was working perfectly fine (Like if I pass a query `{ "city": "edmund" }` it would give me above result) but after the zipQuery it just got messy.

The result of `console.log(zipQuery)` is 49755

Comment: Hi, Can you show us what kind of value is being stored in `zipQuery`. Maybe the result of `console.log(zipQuery)` might do it for us!

Comment: Mentioned that `zipCode` stored in Number, make sure you need convert the `zipQuery` to number as well.

Comment: @Mr.Online apologise for misrepresenting whenever I pass a zipCode in req.body it is giving me a result but city, state and country all three are returning an empty array.

Comment: @YongShun how to convert req.body to a number?

Comment: @YongShun I agree. If the schema says that `zipCode` is a number then constructed query should also be around Number type. Also, You mentioned that your query works fine but it gives an empty array for other which doesn't makes sense until we can see how your query looks like!

Comment: Maybe you can log the query as I mentioned about and share it over here, Maybe then we can know how you're receiving data!

Comment: @Mr.Online question edited. please go through it

Comment: Can you remove $and clause?
```await Parking.find({
          "location.city": { $regex: new RegExp(cityQuery, ($options = "i")) },
          "location.state": { $regex: new RegExp(stateQuery, ($options = "i"))},
          "location.country": { $regex: new RegExp(countryQuery, ($options = "i"))},
          "location.zipCode": zipQuery,
        })```

Comment: Basically my concern is that `$and` seems redundant as by default every keys will act as logical `and` when you use them in query.

Comment: Nope, I tried what you suggested but still getting an empty array

Comment: Here, it seems quiet. No one knows the solution to my problem?